# detect as soon as there is value populated using javascript or entered using keyboard in input field

Tags: javascript

I have written this code which detects if there is a value populated in `productName` field using javascript and then it parses and auto-populate the input field `quantity`. My code only works if `productName` field is populated through **javascript** code and fails to register **keyboard** inputs if I use `onChange`

I want to detect in both scenarios i.e javascript and keyboard, how do I detect using the keyboard in this code?

```js
const input = document.getElementById('productName');

const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(input), 'value');

Object.defineProperty(input, 'value', {
    set: function(t) {
        console.log('Input value was changed programmatically');
         descriptor.set.apply(this, arguments);
         document.getElementById("quantity").value=t
    },
    get: function() {
      return descriptor.get.apply(this);
    }
});

var i=0;
function changeInput(){
/* console.log(document.getElementById('productName').value) */
document.getElementById("productName").value=i++;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="productName" name="productName"  placeholder="product name">
<input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="quantity">
<button onclick="changeInput()">Change</button>
```

Comment: So bind input event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am a beginner in Javascript, a comment by @epascarello helped me, and this was quite easy with binding the input element:

```
 document.getElementById("productName").addEventListener("input",(event)=>{
  document.getElementById("quantity").value= document.getElementById("productName").value;
})
```